# One-to-Many Doctrine relationship not working?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my Symdony2 project I've two related entities: "Reglement and "Article". This should be many-to-one relationship, because each "Reglement" can have many "Articles", and each "Article" can belongs to one "Reglement".
Moreover, I need a user interface to manage Reglement and Articles. So, when adding a Reglement, user should be able to add many articles it belongs.
I've already achieved this by setting up a One-To-Many relation in my Doctrine entites.  Everything is working like a charm, including user interface build on custom form types in Symfony2 (I've used "Collection" form field type to allow user to add "Articles" in "Reglement). The only problem I've is that I can save only the last article in the database !!

Here is my "Reglement" entity source code:

```
<?php

namespace GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Reglement
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\ReglementRepository")
 */

class Reglement
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="domaineApplication", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $domaineApplication;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="texteLegislatif", type="text")
 */
private $texteLegislatif;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contenuText", type="text")
 */
private $contenuText;



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="reglement")
 */
private  $articles;



public function __construct()
{
    $this->articles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->articles;
}

public function setArticles(ArrayCollection $articles)
{
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        $article->addReglement($this);
    }
    $this->articles = $articles;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set domaineApplication
 *
 * @param string $domaineApplication
 * @return Reglement
 */
public function setDomaineApplication($domaineApplication)
{
    $this->domaineApplication = $domaineApplication;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get domaineApplication
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDomaineApplication()
{
    return $this->domaineApplication;
}

/**
 * Set texteLegislatif
 *
 * @param string $texteLegislatif
 * @return Reglement
 */
public function setTexteLegislatif($texteLegislatif)
{
    $this->texteLegislatif = $texteLegislatif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get texteLegislatif
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTexteLegislatif()
{
    return $this->texteLegislatif;
}

/**
 * Set contenuText
 *
 * @param string $contenuText
 * @return Reglement
 */
public function setContenuText($contenuText)
{
    $this->contenuText = $contenuText;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get contenuText
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContenuText()
{
    return $this->contenuText;
}

/**
 * Add articles
 *
 * @param \GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article $articles
 * @return Reglement
 */
public function addArticle(\GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article $articles)
{
    $this->articles[] = $articles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove articles
 *
 * @param \GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article $articles
 */
public function removeArticle(\GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article $articles)
{
    $this->articles->removeElement($articles);
}

}
```

And here is my Article entity source code:

```
<?php

namespace GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */

class Article
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Reglement", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $reglement;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="exigenceArticle", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $exigenceArticle;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set exigenceArticle
 *
 * @param string $exigenceArticle
 * @return Article
 */
public function setExigenceArticle($exigenceArticle)
{
    $this->exigenceArticle = $exigenceArticle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get exigenceArticle
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getExigenceArticle()
{
    return $this->exigenceArticle;
}

/**
 * Set reglement
 *
 * @param \GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Reglement $reglement
 * @return Article
 */
public function setReglement(\GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Reglement $reglement)
{
    $this->reglement = $reglement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get reglement
 *
 * @return \GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Reglement
 */
public function getReglement()
{
    return $this->reglement;
}

public function addReglement(Reglement $reglement)
{
    if (!$this->reglements->contains($reglement)) {
        $this->reglements->add($reglement);
    }
}
}
```

and here is my reglement form :

```
<?php

namespace GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ReglementType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('domaineApplication')
        ->add('texteLegislatif')
        ->add('contenuText')
        ->add('articles', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ArticleType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,

            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            ));
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Reglement'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'gestionenvironnementale_iso14001bundle_reglementtype';
}
}
```

and my article form :

```
<?php

namespace GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('exigenceArticle')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'GestionEnvironnementale\ISO14001Bundle\Entity\Article'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'gestionenvironnementale_iso14001bundle_article';
}
}
```

And here is part of my ReglementController source code:

```
public function ajouterReglementAction()
{

    $reglement = new Reglement();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ReglementType(), $reglement);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $reglement->getArticles()->clear();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($reglement);
            $em->flush();


            foreach ($form->get('articles')->getData() as $ac) {
                $ac->setReglement($reglement);
                $em->persist($ac);
            }
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Reglement bien enregistré');

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('reglement_voir', array('id' => $reglement->getId())));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('ISO14001Bundle:Reglements:ajouter.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

finnally the form view source code :

```
<div class="well">
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <br/>  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('div#gestionenvironnementale_iso14001bundle_reglementtype_articles');
    var $lienAjout = $('<a href="#" id="ajout_article" class="btn">Ajouter un article</a>');
    $container.append($lienAjout);
    $lienAjout.click(function(e) {
        ajouterArticle($container);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    var index = $container.find(':input').length;
    if (index == 0) {
        ajouterArticle($container);
    } else {
        $container.children('div').each(function() {
            ajouterLienSuppression($(this));
        });
    }
    function ajouterArticle($container) {
        var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Article n°' + (index+1))
                .replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, index));
        ajouterLienSuppression($prototype);
        $container.append($prototype);
        index++;
    }
    function ajouterLienSuppression($prototype) {
        $lienSuppression = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');
        $prototype.append($lienSuppression);
        $lienSuppression.click(function(e) {
            $prototype.remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

I hope you can help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi everyone I found the solution of my problem **^_^**

the error is in line 27 of form view, there must be `__name__` instead of `$$name$$` as follows :

```
function ajouterArticle($container) {
    var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Article n°' + (index+1))
            .replace(/__name__/g, index));
    ajouterLienSuppression($prototype);
    $container.append($prototype);
    index++;
}
```

good luck **;)**